# Digits always crashes after submitting valid a phone number on a lenovo A6600d40

Tags: google-fabric

Always happens with any valid 10 digit number on the Lenovo A6600.
It happens with the periscope app as well our own implementation.
I'm only posting on stack overflow since their support forum now redirects here..

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.packagename/com.digits.sdk.android.LoginCodeActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (21 ... 21) ends beyond length 11
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (21 ... 21) ends beyond length 11
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1108)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:680)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:673)
   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
   at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:115)
   at com.digits.sdk.android.SpacedEditText.setSelection(SpacedEditText.java:87)
   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:99)
   at com.digits.sdk.android.SpacedEditText.setText(SpacedEditText.java:68)
   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
   at com.digits.sdk.android.LoginCodeActivityDelegate.setUpEditText(LoginCodeActivityDelegate.java:154)
   at com.digits.sdk.android.LoginCodeActivityDelegate.init(LoginCodeActivityDelegate.java:78)
   at com.digits.sdk.android.DigitsActivity.onCreate(DigitsActivity.java:42)
   at com.digits.sdk.android.LoginCodeActivity.onCreate(LoginCodeActivity.java:26)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6309)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We haven't been able to reproduce this issue, even though we've tried on multiple Lenovo devices. It does seem specific to those devices and if you have a reproducible test case, please raise it up here: https://github.com/crashlytics/digits-android/issues

Comment: @MikeBonnell you should be able to see this crash in Periscope as well. It does crash any app using digits on this particular lenovo device.

Comment: Unfortunately, Fabric is no longer a part of Twitter which owns Periscope.